# Converting hexadecimal to string in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My Current Output is "CURRENT" by ruunign below query

```
select '0x00E70001010E000E430055005200520045004E005400' as Input1
, substr('0x00E70001010E000E430055005200520045004E005400'::varchar, 1, 8)as inpt2
,substr('0x00E70001010E000E430055005200520045004E005400'::varchar, 9, 510)as inpt2
,hex_decode_string(to_varchar('01010E000E430055005200520045004E005400'))as input3
,hex_encode('CURRENT') as inpt4
;
```

But my desired output is "CURRENT", but I am unable to eliminate the special characters.
Can somebody pls help

Comment: Looks as if the hex encoding has extra zeros padding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use regexp_replace to clear unwanted characters:

```
select '0x00E70001010E000E430055005200520045004E005400' as Input1
, substr('0x00E70001010E000E430055005200520045004E005400'::varchar, 1, 8) as inpt2
, substr('0x00E70001010E000E430055005200520045004E005400'::varchar, 9, 510) as inpt2b
, regexp_replace(hex_decode_string( inpt2b ), '[^a-zA-Z0-9]+' ) as input3
, hex_encode(input3) as inpt4test
, hex_encode('CURRENT') as inpt4
;
```

Answer (score 0):

So this one works for me, but it's not straight forward:

```
select ltrim(hex_decode_string(to_varchar(substr('0x00E70001010E000E430055005200520045004E005400'::varchar, 9, 510))), '');
```

Now, when you do this:

```
select hex_decode_string(to_varchar(substr('0x00E70001010E000E430055005200520045004E005400'::varchar, 9, 510)));
```

the output has extra chars in front of **CURRENT**, but if I just copy them and put them in a text file and check with **od** command you will see the extra chars. I just copied them and added to the **ltrim** function:

```
$ cat  test.txt
''
$ od -b test.txt
0000000   047 047 012
0000003
$ od -c test.txt
0000000    '   '  \n
0000003
$ od -An -c test.txt
           '   '  \n

$
```